# Use Microsoft.Azure.Storage in Azure Function csx

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, csx

Somehow I cannot use package `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.blob` in Azure Function v2 using csx.

In extension.proj I have following:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.1.0" />
```

In csx file I have:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
```

And I have error:

```
run.csx(7,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 
'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Full code is on GitHub: https://github.com/ptrstpp950/cognitive-service-azure-function

Comment: I keep telling people this here... ;) If you can do yourself one favor, switch to authoring your Functions in a proper IDE and upload them in compiled form to Azure

Comment: @silent I cannot. I have to make them editable in browser for workshop. I switched to NodeJS. It works like a charm in this case :)

Comment: got it. Yeah, recently had the very same scenario

Comment: @PiotrStapp Can my solution solve your problem? Have any other doubts?

Answer (score 1):

**1.Are you sure of the `extension.proj` you are using?**

From your code I know you are writing on the portal. So you should create `function.proj` instead of `extension.proj` on portal.

**2. I see you write `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.1.0" />` in .proj file. So you should use `#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"` instead of 
    `using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`**

Below is the code of my `function.proj`, things works fine on my side. For more details, have a look of this [Offical doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages).(All of the solution is based on you are using `function 2.x`. If you are using `function 1.x`. It is not the same.)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.1.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

Code of my .crx file:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

Comment: Why `#r Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` instead of `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` ?

Comment: @PiotrStapp For framework assemblies, add references by using the #r "AssemblyName" directive. First add references and then using.  Maybe you need a detailed description of using the .crx file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp

Comment: My description may have a problem, I mean you have to use #r "xxx" to refer to it instead of using `using` directly. This is not the same as in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the package before using it:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```